# hilbert curve implementation in job scheduling

Tags: python, job-scheduling, hilbert-curve

How to implement Hilbert curve algorithm in terms of job scheduling.
Can someone share the logic behind it?

Comment: have you checked wiki? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#Applications_and_mapping_algorithms

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read this first:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: One of best describtions about Hilbert's curve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s7h2MHQtxc Each node in the grid is one partition of your cache and Hilbert's curve guides you trough each "node coordinate".